Create a subset of the correlation matrix that contain only values bigger than 0
How can I create a subset of the correlation matrix that contain only values bigger than 0?
Script:
set.seed(123)
data <- matrix(runif(100, min = 0, max = 1), nrow = 10)
data[, 1] <- 0   
data[, 5] <- 0   
data[, 7] <- 0 
data[, 8] <- 0 
df <- as.data.frame(data)
correlation_matrix <- cor(df)
correlation_matrix <- (correlation_matrix + 1) / 2
correlation_matrix[is.na(correlation_matrix)] <- 0


If the correlation matrix looks like the one in the question then it is sufficient to remove rows (or columns) that are all 0 except for the diagonal.  If the correlation matrix is m then ix <- rowSums(m - diag(diag(m))) != 0; m[ix, ix]

Thanks. how can I save the ix as "matrix" "array" so I can plot it using corrplot?

set.seed(123)
data <- matrix(runif(100, min = 0, max = 1), nrow = 10)
data[, 1] <- 0   
data[, 5] <- 0   
data[, 7] <- 0 
data[, 8] <- 0 
df <- as.data.frame(data)
correlation_matrix <- cor(df)
correlation_matrix <- (correlation_matrix + 1) / 2
correlation_matrix[is.na(correlation_matrix)] <- 0
correlation_matrix

# Identify rows and columns with non-zero values (excluding the diagonal)
ix <- rowSums(correlation_matrix- diag(diag(correlation_matrix))) != 0; correlation_matrix[ix, ix]

# Subset the correlation matrix using ix
correlation_subset <- correlation_matrix[ix, ix]

# Ensure the subset is of class "matrix" for compatibility with corrplot
correlation_subset <- as.matrix(correlation_subset)

# Plot using corrplot with coefficients displayed
library(corrplot)
corrplot(correlation_subset, method = "color",addCoef.col = "black")



I don't think this code is correct. It removes the rows (and columns) with all 0s (except diagonal). But OP asked to keep the rows with all values > 0, that means removing the rows with at least single zero.

However, if you look at the correlation_matrix, you will notice that it contains 0 in each row, so by this logic, you need to delete the entire correlation matrix.
You can check in which row of the matrix there is at least one 0 as follows
apply(correlation_matrix, 1, function(row) any(row == 0))

Probably just a bad example. Otherwise, the Q title should be changed.
